How to pass jar in dataflow operator dag
I want to create a dag using dataflow operator for the below existing command is like,
AA_JAR=jar_1.jar BB_JAR=jar_2.jar java -cp jar_1.jar mydomain.pipline —project=mygcpproject —region=myregion
—serviceAccount=mysa —subnetwork=mynetwork —runner=Dataflow —stagingLocation=gs://testdir/file1
—outputDirectory=gs://testdir2/test2
I got some sample from the net, but not sure how to pass jars, is there any attributes for the dataflow operator?
